# C# Objectlistview - Removal of object but reappear

Tags: c#, visual-studio, objectlistview

I'm currently working on a Objectlistview where we can add tasks and remove them if needed. I've so far everything working like Sorting, adding, grouping and saving / loading to XML.

Now my issue: I have a Menu strip so I can RMB on the row and get access to the command "Remove Task". This execute the next code:

```
objectListView1.RemoveObjects(objectListView1.SelectedObjects);
```

This will remove the selected row and it works as intended but as soon I add a row or edit an object in another row, the removed row just appears again.

I do the following 2 lines if I add a row / edit an existing row:

```
this.objectListView1.SetObjects(ListData.DataList);
```

To refresh the content of the DataList.

```
this.objectListView1.RefreshObjects(ListData.DataList);
```

To update the color of the row depending of data in my last column.

If I use SetObjects() after i remove the row, you can see a short flicker that he did remove the row but shows it again directly after.

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong with the SetObjects / RefreshObjects or that I forgot to add something to let the objectlistview know that I removed a row.

There is nearly no documentation on how to efficiently remove data from an Objectlistview other then to use "RemoveObjects".

Thank you in advance!

Comment: At a wild guess, you are removing objects from `objectListView1` and not from `ListData.DataList`

Comment: Got it working now. It was a fault on my end where I load the data into the list instead of using AddObject() to load it into the ObjectListView. But thanks for your comment, you made me re-think how all this works and got a better understanding of it now.